# scrollbar in jsp with window.open

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs, scroll

i have a big doubt, i would like to use a scroll in my web, my problem is that i call my web from another web and paint my web in a frame of the original web page, but i need to put a scroll in the frame... to call my web page i use a window.open with the property _self. My problem is that in my the frame it dosent appears the scroll bar.

My window open is:

```
 window.open("http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes2?usuario="+document.form1.CLAVEUSU.value,'_self');
```

I put in my window.open scrollbars = true, but it dosent works (i think that is no netcessary to put, because default is true).

Then i have think to solved my problem using a scrollbar in my jsp (where i have my EXTjs code), but i dont know how i can solve this.

Somebody have any idea for my problem?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Post the HTML generated for your page so we can see the problem and how to help.

Comment: I dont use html, that is the problem. I use EXTjs for draw my page.